# Registry Php Example

Tags: php, design-patterns, registry

I have this code which I came across in reading and when I view it in a browser it does not cause any errors. My question is how can the class call `$this->registry` without the property being set. In other words what is the `$this->registry` within the function referring to?

```
class Template{

public function __construct($registry){
    $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

}

this is how I instantiate the classes.

```
<?php
include 'registry.class.php';
include 'template.class.php';
$registry = new Registry();
$template = new Template($registry);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're basically referencing the `Registry` object. Look at it this way:

```
function __construct(Registry $registry) {
    $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

Referencing `$this->registry` is calling the `Templates` "copy" of the `Registry` object. So when you pass the `$registry` object to the `Template` with:

```
$template = new Template($registry);
```

You're basically "giving" the Template class its own `$registry` object.
I've used a similar registry before. Where you can instantiate it like this:

```
$registry = new registry();
$registry->template = new template($registry);
```

Allowing you to access Template methods/vars/etc via the registry:

```
$registry->template->method();
```

---

There will be somebody who can explain the exact happenings a **lot** better than I can right now, but remember, the best way to learn is by trial and error. Learn from your mistakes :-)

---

As per the comments, your `Template` class should look like this:

```
class Template {

    var $registry;

    function __construct($registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }
}
```

That will allow you to access it throughout the class.

Example:

```
function link($url){
    return $this->registry->site->link($url);
}
```

<sup>*The above is a fictional function and the reference to site is also fictional but shows how you could use this class and/or registry.*</sup>

Comment: Thank you but the Template does not have a "copy" of the $registry object (or does it?). If it does I am not declaring it explicitly. What I do not understand is how can I use '->' to reference an object that isn't declared? Is my question clear?

Comment: @Mandela, Are you trying to access it inside the Template class or just in general?

Comment: Inside the template class. I didn't skip any code, the entire class is included in the question. So the `$this->registry` inside the construct belongs to the template class but there is no $registry variable/property declared earlier (or anywhere) in the class.

Comment: Right, and what I am saying is that I do not have the property/variable declared, neither does the example I am looking at, and it is not throwing any errors. @Darren I would normally do it the way you did it but I want to know why the other way (my way) is not throwing an error.

Comment: @Mandela Ahh I see. It doesn't set the error due to the fact that PHP's [`magic methods`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) take effect, instantiating that variable for use within the class scope. [**Look at this example**](https://eval.in/172501) as it shows the happenings.

Comment: Mmm I see. I thought may be it was creating it on the fly but I didn't have enough info to validate that thought. Thank you, It seems that in your example you are also creating stdClass() on the fly as well, would that be correct?
Thank you for the help, appreciated.

Comment: @Mandela Yes the stdClass() is just used as an example to show.

Comment: @Mandela And php's magic methods are just that, magic. It's some Harry Potter voodoo going on there!

Answer (score 0):

`->` is for accessing object fields. So you are setting an object field called registry in the constructor for Template to the value of $registry, which is passed to the constructor. Think for `this->registry` as referring to a variable `registry` in the object `Template`.